# check exact url using jquery if statements are dependent on whole url

Tags: jquery

I am using following code

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("6-girl") > -1){

$("#something").show();

}

if(window.location.href.indexOf("6m") > -1){

$("#else").show();

}
```

Url from both the condition are different still the #something is showing on both pages.why? I am facing same problem with lot of url's. I want to show #something in only "6-girl" url and #else into "6m" only.

Comment: @Blender 6-girl and 6m these are the URLs.Sorry I cannot provide whole url.

Comment: Then those strings are in your URL. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: what hides the elements in the first place? `show()` will only have an affect if element is hidden already

Comment: I just want to match exact URL.It is only checking 6 it is not checking whole URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
var urlTocheck = window.location.href; 

var patternTocheck= /^(6-g)/ ;
var patternTocheckforMen= /^(6m)/ ;

if(patternTocheck.test(urlTocheck))
{
  show 6-girls part
}
else if(patternTocheckforMen.test(urlTocheck))
{
 //show 6m part
}
else
{
  //nothing matched
}
```

Demo : [Regex Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PascX/)

Comment: I have used your code getting this error
Error: ReferenceError: patternTOCheck is not defined.I need seperate If conditions,I dont need if-else there